# What happens if the Internet connection goes down during a Lion Internet Recovery?

Tags: macos, restore, recovery

I am restoring Lion on my MacBook before selling it and I am doing it through the Internet Recovery option. After starting the process, the Internet connection went down a couple of times and, after this happening, the blue progress bar jumped to the end, so I don't know the exact percentage.

Do you know what happens in this case? Does the download resume from where it left or does it start from the beginning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a short interruption, you can expect the download to resume. I might choose to power it off and start over since you might end up with a corrupt package that the OS will not install and a cryptic error message. Worse, the install may stall and you could wait a long time before giving up.

It's in your interest to get the installation over a fast internet connection (perhaps a local Apple Store) so that you don't have to do it over or wait so long in the end.

Comment: The problem is not really the speed of the connection as much as its stability. I am afraid that if I start over again it might crash again...